# Important Update about the CreateVpnGateway API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

i have received below notification from AWS, what will be the impact on existing network if AWS changed it ? we have been configured devices in VPN network

We have identified that you have previously created a Virtual Private Gateway (VGW) for use with AWS Managed VPN and/or AWS Direct Connect. The CreateVpnGateway API is used to create VGWs and we want to make you aware of an update to the CreateVpnGateway API.

As of August 31st 2018, the CreateVpnGateway API will now allow you to specify a private Autonomous System Number (ASN) or the legacy Amazon Public ASN for the VGW. If no ASN is provided, the default value of 64512 will be used.

While we will support the legacy Amazon Public ASN for the foreseeable future, we highly recommend migrating to a private ASN. The use of a private ASN will prevent any accidental route leaks if you advertise your VPC prefixes towards third parties or the Internet

Answer (score 1):

ASN (Autonomous System Number) is used to exchange route information with neighboring autonomous systems which use BGP (Border Gateway Protocol). AWS uses the default ASN of 64512 for the US (7224 for other regions - this varies based upon when you created the VGW).

Normally you want to specify your own ASN, usually a private ASN number so that your routes are not advertised globally. For the time being, there is nothing that you MUST do, but be prepared to eventually select a private ASN from the range 64512 to 65535). Public ASNs are assigned to you and you cannot just pick one. The private ASN must be unique among other private ASNs that your networks use.

Your email states that 64512 is a public ASN, but this is actually a private ASN. Check your VGW to see what ASN is being used. VGWs created before July 1, 2018 using differing numbers (7224, 9059, 10124, etc. based upon region).

I would consult with the adminstrator for your routers (if this is not you) and let him know about this message.